# Trying to recursively detect negatives in a stack?

Tags: c++, loops, recursion

I'm trying to write a function which recursively checks for negative numbers in a stack and then returns the count in the end. The function does not work as intended so far. I think there is something wrong with the loop structure. Any help will be appreciated!

```
   size_t r_appr(stack<int> mystack){       
        int count=0;
        if(!mystack.empty()){
            if(mystack.top()<0){
                count+=1;
            }
            mystack.pop();
            count+=r_appr(mystack);
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: When you say it "does not work as intended", can you give an example input, actual output, and expected output?

Comment: I hope this is an exercise and not something for real code because you are going to make a lot of copies of your stack.

Comment: @greg Hewgill For example, if the function is called as in r_appr(mystack), it should return 4 if mystack contains lets say 10 elements out of which 4 are negative.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense so far. What does *your* function return when given that input?

Comment: Currently, nothing. Blank output.

Comment: I see. Perhaps you could show the code that is supposed to print the output, because that's where the problem seems to be (the code above doesn't contain any output statements). I can't see anything wrong with the above code (I tried it too, it seems to work as expected).

Comment: @GregHewgill If I do cout<<count right before the return statement, the function outputs 0 0 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 4, however I only want 4 as the output. I'm guessing this has to do with the way my loop is set up.

Comment: Well, you're (correctly) seeing the recursion in action if you put the output statement *within* your function. Instead, put the `cout` outside your function.

Comment: @GregHewgill but I want to only call my function outside, I want the cout to happen inside it.

Comment: Recursion means the function runs more than once. If you put the `cout` inside your function, it will output something each time your function runs (which for a stack of size 10, is 11 times). If you only want the final answer and not all the intermediate results, you're going to have to put your `cout` *outside* the function.

Answer (score 0):

I agree @Greg Hewgill.

put `cout` outside the function is normal.

```
int main()
{
    stack<int> s;
    for (c=0; c<5; c++)
        s.push(c*-1);
    cout << r_appr(s);
}
```

put `cout` inside recursive function is a abnormal.

But if you still want to do that, you can use `global variable` or `#define` to achieve.

Below is an example using #define:

```
#define stack_size 4
void r_appr(stack<int> mystack){
    int count=0;
    if(!mystack.empty()){
        if(mystack.top()<0){
            count+=1;
        }
        mystack.pop();
        count+=r_appr(mystack);
        if (mystack.size()==stack_size)
            cout << count << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    stack<int> s;
    for (c=0; c<=stack_size; c++)
        s.push(c*-1);
    r_appr(s);
}
```

If you want your stack size is a variable, use `global variable` can do that.
(But it's not proper in Object-oriented programming.)